Creating static horizontal line at particular price for tommorows date
Here is the code written in pinescript. but line is not showing in the chart. Need suggestion to correct my code.
indicator("My script",overlay = true)
//price = input(100.0,title = "price")
//tomorrow = timestamp(2024,08,08,09,15,00)
sessionstart = timestamp(2024,08,08,09,15)+86400000
sessionend = sessionstart+86400000
//plot(sessionstart)
//plot(timestamp(2024,08,08,15,20,00),color = color.black)
//sessionend = math.min(timestamp(2024,08,08,15,20,00),timenow + 509*60*1000)
//if(timenow >= sessionstart and timenow<=sessionend)
line.new(sessionstart,2915,sessionend,2915,xloc.bar_time,color = color.blue,width = 2)

i tried above code, but it is not working, need to correct my code from experts.

Your script works.

I just cleaned up your code.
//@version=5
indicator("My script",overlay = true)
price = input(2915.0,title = "price")
sessionstart = input.time(timestamp("08 12 2024 9:15"), "Start")
sessionend = sessionstart+86400000
line.new(sessionstart,price,sessionend,price,xloc.bar_time,color = color.blue,width = 2)

